# Preloaded Shiny Server Apps work fine however own apps failing to start?

Tags: r, shiny, digital-ocean, shiny-server, ubuntu-18.04

Working on deploying a Shiny App on my own domain through a Digital Ocean.

After completing all the installation procedures I can access the :3838 port fine and that is displaying the welcome to shiny server page just fine, as well as the :3838/sample-apps/hello page also working as planned however when i try and bring up my own app that has been loaded onto the server I get an error warning saying that the "The application failed to start." and that "The application exited during initialization."

When I look a little deeper into the logs it brings up the following however I have yet to be able to find a solution.

> Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : cannot open file
>   '/srv/shiny-server/ESapp/global.R': Permission denied Error in
>   readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : cannot open the connection Calls:
>   runApp ->  -> sourceUTF8 -> readUTF8 -> readLines Execution
>   halted

UPDATE: When I pull up the stats for each directory/file this is what I'm getting under the access heading:

Sample apps

> Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root)

Own apps

> Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x) Uid: ( 1000/ alyssa) Gid: ( 1001/shiny-apps)

UPDATE 2 :

Recent trials have indicated that this is a shiny problem not a ubuntu permissions problem as previously thought

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing `Permission denied` as a dominating error there. When you look on the console, how to the owner/group ids and permissions compare between your app directory and files when compared with the sample-apps dirs/files?

Comment: Please amend additional information into your original question where you can use the full power of text and code formatting.

Comment: Did you see [here](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/rstudio-and-shiny-server-connection-problems-127-0-0-1-refused-to-connect)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik sorry fixed it :)

Comment: @A.Suliman Yeah I followed an updated version of the deanattali tutorial. Also that's actually sort of helpful? Clearly the same problem but I just don't know HOW to change the user files.

Comment: Log into your machine and chmod the hell out of those files?